# Navigation caching only when navigating back

Tags: c#, navigation, uwp

I have a little bit of experience programming Android apps.
And now i am wondering if the same thing is possible:
(Android:)
When navigating in an android app between activities, the state of the previous activity is hold. By pressing the back button, you get the previous activity the way you left it. When navigating towards an activity, this opens the activity in the default state.

(UWP:)
Navigating between pages:
I have a page which should be cached for when i navigate back.
But when I navigate towards the page, it should open the page in the initial state.

How is this possible?
(I already am able to enable navigationcachemode. I wonder if i can disable it, or create a new instance of the page for example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
            NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;

        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }
```

Just disable the NavigationMode when you're navigating back from a page. So you force the creation of a new page when you'll navigate again to that page (and the NavigationMode will be set to the NavigationMode you set in the constructor or XAML).